# How to apply Data Table Jquery file to ASP Grid view controls?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

I have a Data Table .Js file for table its working fine.Now I want to apply that Js files to my ASP Grid, But it is not working.Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Js files:

```
    <script src="lib/datatables/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
     <script src="lib/datatables/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>
   <script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {

        metisTable();
        metisSortable();
    });
</script>
```

Html code:

```
     <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>Rendering engine</th>
                      <th>Browser</th>
                      <th>Platform(s)</th>
                      <th>Engine version</th>
                      <th>CSS grade</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Trident</td>
                      <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
                      <td>Win 95+</td>
                      <td>4</td>
                      <td>X</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>Trident</td>
                      <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
                      <td>Win 95+</td>
                      <td>5</td>
                      <td>C</td>
                    </tr>

                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

I want to convert this HTML code to ASP Grid.Please help me.

Comment: "It's not working."   You're going to have to do better than that.  And perhaps some code?

Comment: I want to Use same DataTable.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, you are trying to get a GridView control to render the above HTML? If so, give this a try...

Example.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication3
{
    public partial class Example : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var data = new List<Browser>
            {
                new Browser {
                    RenderingEngine = "Trident",
                    Name = "Internet Explorer 4.0",
                    Platforms = "Win 95+",
                    EngineVersion = "4",
                    CssGrade = "X"
                },
                new Browser {
                    RenderingEngine = "Trident",
                    Name = "Internet Explorer 5.0",
                    Platforms = "Win 95+",
                    EngineVersion = "5",
                    CssGrade = "C"
                }
            };


            dataTable.DataSource = data;
            dataTable.DataBind();

            // tell gridview to wrap header row in a THEAD
            dataTable.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
        }
    }

    class Browser
    {
        public string RenderingEngine { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Platforms { get; set; }
        public string EngineVersion { get; set; }
        public string CssGrade { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Example.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Example.aspx.cs" EnableViewState="false" Inherits="WebApplication3.Example" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="dataTable" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped" runat="server">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Rendering engine" DataField="RenderingEngine" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Browser" DataField="Name" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Platform(s)" DataField="Platforms" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Engine version" DataField="EngineVersion" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="CSS grade" DataField="CssGrade" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

The HTML generated should have the structure you're looking for. You may have to tweak it with some CSS...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>

    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="Example" id="form1">
        <div class="aspNetHidden">
            <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="7dkQ7oSHomhL10KJ/ok2e80Vvp9y2YD39bh5p/Adhqkq0dVg1ZTchTib8qBNWZHWJJGmLATzADBKv9sLEXo4fhGXQTPTW66PXWGMd8YJLSeX18oHaCRD34u6tpEivBBJ" />
        </div>

        <div>
            <div>
                <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-hover table-striped" cellspacing="0" rules="all" border="1" id="dataTable" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th scope="col">Rendering engine</th>
                            <th scope="col">Browser</th>
                            <th scope="col">Platform(s)</th>
                            <th scope="col">Engine version</th>
                            <th scope="col">CSS grade</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Trident</td>
                            <td>Internet Explorer 4.0</td>
                            <td>Win 95+</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                            <td>X</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Trident</td>
                            <td>Internet Explorer 5.0</td>
                            <td>Win 95+</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                            <td>C</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    <!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
    <script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
        {"appName":"Chrome","requestId":"7975235c58f0487da9dfd4fc5eec6dad"}
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:50342/8ac48e89e4e94137abf12bc60954c99f/browserLink" async="async"></script>
    <!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for reply.In gridview, datatable js working fine.But Gridview size is extended to right then original size of grid, after adding datatable.